# PHP get values starting from the indexed variable

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
$map[ ]='A,R,T,E,D,C,B,X,Y';
```

If i search for element C then function must return 6 elements starting from C .If last element is reached again it must traverse from start of array

Example

**OUTPUT** will be C,B,X,Y,A,R

If i search for value B then function must return below

**OUTPUT** will be B,X,Y,A,R,T

If i search for T

**OUTPUT** will be T,E,D,C,B,X

Comment: looks like a homework, what do you have so far?

Comment: Clues: [array_search()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php); [array_slice()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

Comment: its not a homework,tags are stored in database,i am fetching them but need the above logic implemented in frontend

Comment: Note: That is not a valid array definition syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = explode(',','A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H');
$element = 'E';
$a = array_search($element, $array);

for($i = 0;$i<6;$i++) {
    if($a == count($array)) $a = 0;
    echo $array[$a];
    $a++;
}
```

Do you need something like this?

Comment: Got worked ..thank you  http://codepad.org/G6cIOimI

Answer (score 1):

```
$newarray = array(0 => 'A', 1 => 'R', 2 => 'T', 3 => 'E', 4 => 'D', 5 => 'C', 6 => 'B', 7 => 'X', 8 => 'Y');

$element = 'B';
$keyM = array_search($element,$newarray);
$o=0;
$k=$keyM;
while($o < 6)
{
    if(isset($newarray[$k]))
    {
        echo $newarray[$k];
    }else{
        $k=0;
        echo $newarray[$k];
    }
    echo'<br>';
    $k++;
    $o++;
}
```

Here you go